# How to execute more then one method of a spring bean on app startup

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, startup

I have a spring bean with 4 blocking queues. Each queue is assigned a method (named processQueueX() ) which calls take() on that queue and processes taken object from queue.

I want to call each of those method in a separate thread on app startup.
I tried with task scheduler and fixed-delay setting but that in some way blocks tomcat and it stops responding to requests. Each method needs to be called once, so scheduling was a bad idea I guess.

Init method does not work also since it works in a single thread, each method has endless loop to process queue forever.

Is there a way to call these methods declaratively from spring config file in manner similar to task namespace? Or programmatically?

Tnx

Comment: If the queues block, do they need to be processed on separate threads? In which case, how do you propose starting up the 4 threads? Is that your question?

Comment: Yup, that is the question. How to execute 4 methods each in separate thread on app startup

Answer (score 0):

I think using scheduler not a bad idea use quart scheduler with simple trigger thus quarz will do threading for you and tomcat not effected .And configure  quartz with just enough number of thread.

Answer (score 0):

Would [23.4. The Spring TaskExecutor abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor) help?

Where the example has a `MessagePrinterTask` class, you would have similar, but your `run()` method would access one of the queues. You would set up your Spring config to inject one of the queues into the task, so depending on how similar your queues are, you might be able to use the same `Runnable` task.